# The Tiniest (closest to 0) Ever number in scientific notation possible in R

Tags: r, function

**Background:**

I need to use a number for a function that is absolutely closest to ZERO but not Exactly ZERO (i.e., a tiny bit larger then ZERO).

**Question:**

I'm wondering how I can find the tiniest (closest to 0) Ever number in scientific notation possible in R?

Comment: Note that this is often referred to as machine zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.Machine$double.xmin
```

From `?.Machine`

> double.xmin
>
> the smallest non-zero normalized floating-point number, a
>   power of the radix, i.e., double.base ^ double.min.exp. Normally
>   2.225074e-308.

Comment: Thanks very much. May I ask how we can find the closest number to +1 (but a tiny bit smaller) as well?

Comment: Your answer can be found in `?.Machine`

Comment: Honestly, couldn't locate that one!

Comment: I think double.neg.eps is the one you're looking for

Comment: Actually, no, that gives: `0.0000000000000001110223`! I need something like `.999999999999999999999999999999`

Comment: Read the description of what it represents. It should be clear that you can use that number to get what you need.